# Do extrinsic respect changes to storage due on call?

Tags: storage, extrinsic

I have pretty simple extrinsic code which stores data to substrate storage hashmap and tries to load it after from another nested function. But result looks like nothing stored.
In pseudo:

```
storage["key"] = 1
...
storage.get("key")  // it is None
```

I know that all operations of extrinsic are transactional, but... is this expected behavior, or I did something wrong?

Comment: Can you give us the full code on GitHub or so? It should be stored.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I will try to make some small example to reproduce. Give me couple of days.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi No luck with short example. Anyway, we changed the way we did it. So, if I faced this again, I will update OP post and tag you.